# R: wrong arithmetic for big numbers

Tags: r, biginteger

I encountered a problem in R when it's performing simple arithmetic for big numbers incorrectly. Can someone explain what's happening, and how to work around?

```
> a <- 51569
> b <- a + 6924851946518374722
> b
[1] 6924851946518425600 # problem is visible here already
> c <- b - 6924851946518374722
> c
[1] 51200
```

So there's an error of 469 when adding the big number. Why?

Comment: This is because these numbers are stored as floating-point.

Answer (score 5):

R uses double-precision floating-point to represent values.  The precision depends on your machine.  On my Intel machine with IEEE doubles, I get 52 bits of precision:

```
> options(digits=22)
> (0:1) + 2^52
[1] 4503599627370496 4503599627370497
> (0:1) + 2^53
[1] 9007199254740992 9007199254740992
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is there any way to work around it? Something like bignum in python limited by memory size?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any R big integer package.  For most analysis, floating point works well; one part in 4 quadrillion is good enough.

Comment: R has a package that wraps gmp: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/gmp.pdf Note also that R still does not support 64 bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

R has a package that wraps GMP, the gnu multiple precision library:

[CRAN: R gmp manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/gmp.pdf)

```
library(gmp)
a <- as.bigz("51569")
b <- a + as.bigz("6924851946518374722")
c <- b - as.bigz("6924851946518374722")
c

Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 51569
```

As pointed out in a comment, the quotes are necessary.

```
as.bigz(6924851946518374722) # Does not work as intended
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 6924851946518374400
```

because otherwise R converts the argument to a double, losing precision before converting to `bigz`.

Note also that R does not yet support 64 bit integers, e.g.

```
[1] 4294967296L
Warning message:
non-integer value 4294967296 qualified with L; using numeric value
```