# Why does R display wrong number with large numbers?

Tags: r, math, largenumber

When I save a large number in R as an object the wrong number is saved? Why is that?

```r
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)
num <- 201912030032451613 

num
#> [1] 201912030032451616
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600569/r-wrong-arithmetic-for-big-numbers

Comment: You really need to read some explanations about floating-point numbers.

Comment: Sure, do you have any recommended links Roland?

Comment: A classic article: [What Every Computer Scientists Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). This is nearly 30 years old, but is still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Roland says, this is a floating point issue (the Wikipedia page on floating point numbers is as good as anything). Unpacking it a bit though, R has *specific* integer format but it is limited to 32 bit integers:

```r
> str(-2147483647L)
 int -2147483647
> str(2147483647L)
 int 2147483647
> str(21474836470L)
 num 21474836470
Warning message:
non-integer value 21474836470L qualified with L; using numeric value
```

So, when R gets your number it is storing it as a floating point number not an integer. Floating point numbers are limited in how much precision they can store and typically only have about 17 significant digits. Because your number has more significant digits than that there is loss of precision. Losing precision in the smallest digits doesn't usually matter for computer arithmetic, but if your big number is a key of some kind (or a date stamp) then you are in more trouble. The `bit64` package is designed with this kind of use case in mind, or you could import it as a string, depending on what you want to do.