# R: Full Calculations for Large Numbers

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I noticed the following:

```
 > 3^83
[1] 3990838394187339732048206468684268226400

> 2^51
[1] 2251799813685248
```

**The problem happens when I try to subtract these two numbers:**

```
> 3^83 - 2^51
[1] 3990838394187339732048206468684268226400
```

As we can see, the subtraction of these two numbers results in a number that is equal to the bigger number - this is impossible!

**Can someone please show me why this is happening and what can I do to correct this error so that the subtraction is correct?**

Thanks!

**Note 1:**

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

> options()$digits
[1] 7
```

**Note 2:** Is it possible that the GMP library (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) might be able to fix this problem? For example:

```
library(gmp)

 num = as.bigz(3)

 a=num^96
 #a
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 6362685441135942358474828762538534230890216321

 num1=as.bigz(2)
 b=3*(num1^96)
 # b
#  Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 237684487542793012780631851008

 a-b

#  Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 6362685441135942120790341219745521450258365313
```

Comment: are you on a 32bit machine?

Comment: @ KU99: Thank you for your reply! I think I am not:

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Comment: what is the value of `options()$digits`?

Comment: > options()$digits
[1] 7

Comment: Then why do you have the many numbers printed above? I am unable to reprduce issue anyway

Comment: Actually the number is not big. Note that you are doing `3^83-2^51` yet you previously have `3^84` 84 and 83 are 2 different indices resulting in two different results. A smaller number to be precise

Comment: I think the GMP library might help here?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600853/5635580)?